# How to use a separated user with GUI on OpenBSD?

Tags: security, x11, users, openbsd

A webbrowser is a GREAT attack vector since people use it to access the "dangerous" internet. Very bad things can come in through to the desktop.

So in general for a desktop, we can do the following: have a separated*, ex.: "firefox" user that we use only for running the Firefox webbrowser.

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Ports 44444 # increased port number to avoid simpler automated attacks
ListenAddress 127.0.0.1 # only listen on localhost!
PasswordAuthentication no # allow only pubkey
PubkeyAuthentication yes # allow only pubkey
etc.

And of course we could limit in pf who can have access to port 44444, have port knocking, etc.
```

Then the normal "user" start firefox with this

```
ssh -p 44444 firefox@127.0.0.1 -X /home/firefox/.firefox/firefox-bin > /dev/null 2>&1
```

**The Question is:** Are there any better solution to use the webbrowser with a separated user? I didn't find "gksu" in the ports. Asking it specifically for OpenBSD using the default FVWM.

Why isn't the SSH solution OK? AFAIK:

```
- Using "ssh -X" is not a very secure solution
- Using "ssh -X" can cause performance problems for the webbrowser
```

*using a separated user we can limit the attack, so the attacker will not see the normal user "user"'s private files if it gets in to the desktop via the browser.

UPDATE#1: copy&paste function should work for the webbrowser that we use with the separated user.